# HTML & ASP Classic "After Load" event?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I'm using HTML & ASP Classic. Does someone knows if there is something like "After Load" event?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you need this event? Client side or server side?

Comment: Are you talking about the client side (browser) or the context of a page render and page postback introduced with ASP.NET?

Comment: I need in on the client side. Once all the page is loaded and the user can see it, I need to do something in the background.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options, depending on what you need to do.

On the client side, if you are using javascript, you can use the `OnLoad` event that will fire once the page has finished loading. This is commonly done on the `<body>` tag and calls a javascript function of your choice:

```
<body onload="myFunction();">
```

If you are using a javascript library like jQuery, it has some built in functionality that helps with this.

If you are looking for a server side event that will tell you that the page has finished loading, there is no such event (classic or asp.net). One way to emulate such a thing would be by using a javascript function to make an http request (using `XMLHttpRequest`) to the server to let it know the page has finished loading.

Comment: The onload event fires after all the page is loaded?

Comment: Yes. After all static content has finished loading.

Comment: Then I'm probably missing something...
this is the case; I have on the html file a XML tag: <xml id="xml1" OnCellChange="DoSomething()" </xml>.
The problem is that the function DoSomething() is called before any cell was changed.....So I wanted to reverse waht DoSomething() does, after the page loads.

Comment: @user181421 - The `<xml>` tag is not part of the HTML specification, and as such HTML does not have a `OnCellChange` event defined on it. I wouldn't expect it to work.

Comment: @user181421 - This makes it an IE XML and Javascript issue, not classic asp or html.

Comment: @user181421 - how do you populate the XML island? If you do so in script, then I would expect the event to get fired.